# Excel: Match\Index specific column based on multiple criteria

Tags: excel, indexing, range, match, vlookup

I have two Tables, Table 1 Column A is a rolling date column. Table 2 consists of four columns of differing "Trigger Dates".  Table 2, Column 1 contains an Annual trigger, ie occurs once a year.  Table 2 Column 2 contains Bi-Annual Triggers, and occurs twice yearly. Table 2 Column 3 contains Monthly Triggers, "12 dates" and Table 2 Column 4 contains Weekly Triggers, "52 dates".

Ok, so what I'm looking for is to a formula that will return the date trigger, where Table 1 Column 1 matches a condition (Annually, Bi-Annually, Monthly, Weekly) selected in a cell "we'll say F1, outside of any ranges that may be created.

**Example:** If Table 1 Col 2 = "01/02/2013" and I select "Weekly" in F1, the formula will look in the weekly Column in Table 2 to determine if "01/02/2013" exists.

I've allocated a named range to each column in Table 2
I've allocated a named range to the condition in F1 which is a drop down list

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You might try:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,INDIRECT(CHAR(72+MATCH(F$1,$I$1:$L$1,0))&":"&CHAR(72+MATCH(F$1,$I$1:$L$1,0))),1,0),"")
```

[image: SO19542409 example]

Comment: Ok, I've tried: =IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP([@Col2],INDIRECT("Table2["&$F$1&"]"),1,FALSE)),"No","Yes")

I come across a volatile issue within the INDIRECT("Table2["&$F$1&"]"), possibly because I'm using excel 2003...

Also, please forgive my ignorance, [@Col2] refers to the value in table 1 I'm looking for in table 2.  I've not come across this expression before. I've replaced this with the cell I'm cell in Table1 I'm using to cross reference.

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so supposing your Range Name is in `F1`, your formula to find the match would look as follows:

```
=If(IsError(Match(LookupVal,Indirect(F1),0)),"No Match", "Match")
```

...Something along those lines

Hope this helps point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

`INDIRECT` and `VLOOKUP` will be your friends here.

I constructed Table2 just as you had described, with the *Annual,Bi-annual,Monthly,Weekly* labels for the columns in the table - this will avoid having to keep named ranges up to date, as it's looking directly at the table in the formula

For the function, I then used VLOOKUP to find the date, in the column referenced by F1.
Column Reference: `INDIRECT("Table2["&$F$1&"]")`
Find Value: `VLOOKUP([@Col2],INDIRECT("Table2["&$F$1&"]"),1,FALSE)` (looking at column 1 in the return values, as I don't really care what value is returned.
This will return the date if found, and an error if not. I can then wrap the result in the `IF(ISERROR(` so I can return Yes or No if the date is found.

This produces the entire formula of

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP([@Col2],INDIRECT("Table2["&$F$1&"]"),1,FALSE)),"No","Yes")
```

for the next column in Table1, so that when I change the value in F1, it will look for that column name in Table2, and let me know if it is found.

Comment: Ok, I've tried: 

=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP([@Col2],INDIRECT("Table2["&$F$1&"]"),1,FALSE)),"No","Yes")

Comment: Example of table with formula in action: http://wikisend.com/download/644738/questions.19542409.xlsx